# IPad like overlay popup window

Tags: wpf, xaml

how would one do an IPad like overlay window like this
in WPF with XAML
[image]

I thought about a toggle button to or an expander control.
It would be nice if the panel is scaleable. 
I have the most trouble with the centric overlay that has different size then the button itself.

Any help, links or resources would be great.

Comment: How about the actual WPF [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx)? I would create a class called PopupButton to handle all that. But using Popup can be sometimes quite tricky. Especially when you want to close them by clicking outside, of when you click a button inside. The best way to learn how to use them, is looking in the Overflow logic in the WPF Toolbar classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dowhilefor is correct, the Popup class is the way to go - I made a small sample project using a Popup with a custom control as the child. Of importance are the PlacementTarget and Placement fields of Popup, as they let you set where the popup appears. Hope this helps!

[image: Popup example]

Custom control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverfighterTest.PopupControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Clone</Button>
        <Button>Log Call</Button>
        <Button> Visit Report</Button>
        <Button> Delete</Button>
        <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window with popup:

```
<Window x:Class="SilverfighterTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverfighterTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="rect" MouseLeftButtonDown="rect_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Red">

    </Rectangle>

    <Popup PopupAnimation="Slide" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=rect}"  Name="thePopup" >
        <local:PopupControl/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Code behind for the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void rect_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        thePopup.IsOpen = !thePopup.IsOpen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example... Is there a chance to have the Popup centric below the rectangle? Or Right aligned like in my screenshot?

Comment: Glad to help :) you can set the HorizontalOffset property of the popup control to adjust the alignment to your liking. thePopup.HorizontalOffset = -1 * rect.ActualWidth; should right align the popup for my example.

Comment: but this is in codebehind obviously ... I asume there is no XAML way other then writing a converter or attached property

Comment: correct, not that I can think of other than writing a converter, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the help... I actually end up using a toggle button to show hide the pop up via element binding. But it did the trick... thanks